# Removing the Edit on Github link when using Read The Docs & Sphinx with ReadTheDocs Theme

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm trying to find out how to use the _template overrides option in Sphinx to override the default ReadTheDocs theme for hosting Sphinx documentation on http://readthedocs.org.

Specifically, I'm wanting to remove/hide the "Edit on Github" link shown in the upper right hand corner of this theme.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

I've reviewed the documentation here: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html, however, I'm stumped and really need some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out so I'll answer my own inquiry in hopes to assist others.

Assuming you're using the ReadTheDocs default theme this should work just fine.

- Clone the ReadTheDocs theme from the Github repo to your computer. (https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme/)
- Locate `breadcrumbs.html` file (https://github.com/snide/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/master/sphinx_rtd_theme/breadcrumbs.html)
- Add `breadcrumbs.html` file to your Sphinx documentation folder in the `_templates` folder. *If this directory doesn't yet exist you'll need to create it.*
- In your `conf.py` file locate your `html_context` section, if you do not already have this, you can create it. (Sample linked below).

  `html_context = {
  "display_github": False, # Add 'Edit on Github' link instead of 'View page source'
  "last_updated": True,
  "commit": False,
  }`
- Add the `breadcrumbs.html` file to your tracked files using `Git`
- Commit the changes to your `conf.py`
- Push to remote Github repo
- Profit

References

- https://github.com/duelingdogs/dueling-docs/blob/master/source/conf.py#L36-L40
- http://help.duelingdogs.net/en/latest/ (Example showing that the `Edit on Github` option is now removed.

Answer (score 1):

The Read the Docs documentation has similar instructions: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/remove-edit-buttons.html#. So perhaps there've been underlying code changes since the original answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

My needs was very similar but not exactly the same. I wanted to both remove this link for generated pages ("search" and "genindex"), and change the link text because we use framagit as a project hosting.

Here is my version at the end:

```
{%- extends "sphinx_rtd_theme/breadcrumbs.html" %}

{% block breadcrumbs_aside %}
  <li class="wy-breadcrumbs-aside">
    {% if hasdoc(pagename) and pagename != "search" and pagename != "genindex" %}
      <a href="{{ meta['framagit_url'] }}" class="fa fa-bitbucket"> {{ _('Edit on FramaGit') }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
{% endblock %}
```

See it live here:
https://framagit.org/simgrid/simgrid/tree/master/docs/source