# Removing the view source link when using Read The Docs & Sphinx with ReadTheDocs Theme

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

Is there any way to remove the "View page source" link from a sphinx generated read the docs theme page?

[image]

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019670/removing-the-edit-on-github-link-when-using-read-the-docs-sphinx-with-readthed?rq=1) and it recommends finding the breadcrumbs file, but I can't find one

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your `conf.py` file, try setting the variable `html_show_sourcelink` to `False`,

```
html_show_sourcelink = False
```

If it does not exist, just create it. Then, compile again the project,

```
$ make html
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't be fooled by the configuration. You can see the source code.

In fact, from the [HTML theming support](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.2/theming.html#creating-themes) of Sphinx, it introduced that the structure of a theme should look like this.

```
[theme]
inherit = base theme
stylesheet = main CSS name
pygments_style = stylename
sidebars = localtoc.html, relations.html, sourcelink.html, searchbox.html
...
```

here is [site-packages/sphinx_rtd_theme/theme.conf](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/38752d455ff0206678e7d9ac591c4237f8af6226/sphinx_rtd_theme/theme.conf#L2)

```
[theme]
inherit = basic
stylesheet = css/theme.css
pygments_style = default
```

So we know that its sidebars completely inherited from basic.

What is **basic**? One of the themes of the sphinx.

[site-packages/sphinx/theme/](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/f9968594206e538f13fa1c27c065027f10d4ea27/sphinx/themes)  {[basic](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/f9968594206e538f13fa1c27c065027f10d4ea27/sphinx/themes/basic), [nature](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/f9968594206e538f13fa1c27c065027f10d4ea27/sphinx/themes/nature)...}

The contents of [site-packages/sphinx/themes/basic/sourcelink.html](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/f9968594206e538f13fa1c27c065027f10d4ea27/sphinx/themes/basic/sourcelink.html#L10-L18)

```html
...
{%- if show_source and has_source and sourcename %}
  <div role="note" aria-label="source link">
    <h3>{{ _('This Page') }}</h3>
    <ul class="this-page-menu">
      <li><a href="{{ pathto('_sources/' + sourcename, true)|e }}"
            rel="nofollow">{{ _('Show Source') }}</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
{%- endif %}
```

(If you are confused with this format, please reference here: [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/)))

And then, we know that show if and only if the `show_source`, `has_source`, `sourcename` all the True.

What is `show_source`, `has_source`, `sourcename` ?

If your format is HTML, then it's coming from: [sphinx.builders.html StandaloneHTMLBuilder](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/a969e90f28e0ade11b4c38d9a6e6f3264d1bf971/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py#L176)

Among them, he created a variable `globalcontext`, see below:

```py
class StandaloneHTMLBuilder(Builder):
    ...

    def prepare_writing(...):
        ...
        self.globalcontext = {
            'has_source': self.config.html_copy_source,
            'show_source': self.config.html_show_sourcelink,
        }
        ...
        
    ...
    
    def get_doc_context(...):
        ...
        # the name for the copied source
        if self.config.html_copy_source:
            sourcename = docname + source_suffix
            if source_suffix != self.config.html_sourcelink_suffix:
                sourcename += self.config.html_sourcelink_suffix
        else:
            sourcename = ''
```

---

Click the link if you want to see the full code

- [prepare_writing](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/a969e90f28e0ade11b4c38d9a6e6f3264d1bf971/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py#L493-L494)
- [get_doc_context](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/a969e90f28e0ade11b4c38d9a6e6f3264d1bf971/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py#L566-L571)

---

Now, I think you already get it.

**has_source** is **html_copy_source**

**show_source** is **html_show_sourcelink**

and `sourcename = ... if html_copy_source else ''`

So, the close way has two, both ok.

1. `html_copy_source = False` (since [has_source](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/a969e90f28e0ade11b4c38d9a6e6f3264d1bf971/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py#L493) + [html_copy_source](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/82501a6f6ff1e037d6f8fed12b257e8cdb9c34a7/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py#L566-L569))
2. `html_show_sourcelink = False` (since [show_source](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/a969e90f28e0ade11b4c38d9a6e6f3264d1bf971/sphinx/themes/basic/sourcelink.html#L10) + [htm_show_sourcelink](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/a969e90f28e0ade11b4c38d9a6e6f3264d1bf971/sphinx/builders/html/__init__.py#L494) )

*(or 3. both eq False ...)*

Comment: Lord, is that you?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work in my side with @lucasrodesg's answer, my Sphinx vertion is 1.8.2, I just removed 'sphinx.ext.viewcode' of extensions variable in the conf.py and worked.  Just like in the following code, uncomment the last line.

```
extensions = [
'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
'sphinx.ext.doctest',
'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
'sphinx.ext.todo',
'sphinx.ext.coverage',
'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
# 'sphinx.ext.viewcode',]
```

Comment: Same here. Turning off `html_show_sourcelink` did not work for me, but this did. Thank you!!